# Write download function for file on web server to client PC.

Tags: c#, jquery

Hi there i need to write a download function so when the the user of my web site clicks a button the file is downloaded to there PC.

If i use this as a link then the file will be downloaded:

```
http://formvalue.co.za/download/" + fileName + ".xlsx"
```

But there i cant do any thing after that, so i need this in a function so that i can delete the file off of my server after it has been downloaded.

I am using MVC, so the function can be in Jquery or in C#.

Can anyone please help, If you need any info please ask, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the link have to match that exact format? Would this work? http://formvalue.co.za/download?file=whatever.xlsx

Comment: What would ? instead of / do?

Comment: Nothing on its own, it was a direct question...

Comment: weather it worked or not, its not a function to download the file, its just a link, and a link being a url  will direct my page to the download and then i cant do any thing after that, I would like to run delete code after the download but cant if im using a link.

Answer (score 1):

Could you simply use a LinkButton that posts back to the server and calls the following method?

```
internal static void ContentToBrowser(string contentType, string filename, string content)
        // Send to browser
        var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.Clear();
        response.ContentType = contentType;
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", 
                    String.Format("attachment; filename=\"{0}\"", filename));
        var contentLength = response.ContentEncoding.GetByteCount(content);
        response.AddHeader("Content-Length", contentLength.ToString());
        response.Write(content);
        response.End();
}
```

This allows you to write the required content directly back to the client without worrying about storing in on the server. e.g.

```
protected void LinkButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string filename = @"c:\filepath\blah.xlsx";
     string content = File.ReadAllText(filename);
     ContentToBrowser("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "downloaded-blah.xlsx", content);
     File.Delete(filename);
}
```

However, I have to question your motives for deleting the file afterward. How do you know it has been successfully downloaded and stored by the client?

Comment: But the file is on my server, i want to download it to the client, im unsure what this code does?

Comment: The above code will write the content of a file directly back to the client with the specified filename and contentType. If the file is on your server you could read in the file then use this method to return it to the client and delete it afterward.

Comment: So what goes into contentType and content?

Comment: Where did you get this code, please link me so i can see it in context.